# PHP Redirect with multiple parameters

Tags: php, redirect

I have my dashboard.php as a template page. I have a view.php page where all user details can be viewed. The page also has Edit and Delete buttons to edit and delete the user. I have all redirects pointed to dashboard.php.
For edit and delete actions, I need to pass id and action(either edit or delete) to dashboard.php as:

```
<td>
    <a href="dasbboard.php?page=user_action&id=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>&action=edit">Edit</a> 
    || 
    <a href="modules/user/action.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>&action=delete">Delete</a> 
</td>
```

My dashboard.php looks like this:

```
<?php 
    //home page
        if($page=="home" or $page=="")  {include_once 'home.php';} 
    //user related
        else if($page=="profile")       {include_once 'modules/user/view.php';} 
        else if($page=="create_user")   {include_once 'modules/user/add.php';} 
        else if($page=="user_action")   {include_once 'modules/user/action.php';}
        else                            {include_once 'home.php';}?>
```

Now the problem is, when I try to get the page name using `$_GET['page']`, it gives me the whole thing: `page=user_action&id=30&action=edit`.
Is there any way that I can just get the `page=user_action` in my dashboard.php instead of all the string after `&`?

Comment: `$_GET['page']` should give you just `user_action`. Can you please edit your question and paste the final generated URL that the code produces? I suspect something in the formatting is not correct.

Comment: If your link `dasbboard.php?page=user_action&id=30&action=edit`, `$_GET['page']` give user_action. I tried in localhost and it  worked. What's your `$page` variables? `$page = $_GET['page'];` ?